# How to detect if the user cancels a transaction in Metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I want to detect if the user has clicked a button that will make metamask popup asking them to submit, but then rejects the transaction. I have something like the following:

```
Contract.deployed().then(function (contractInstance) {
        contractInstance.function({ from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function (error, result) {

            if (!error) {
                console.log('ok')
            } else {
                if (error.message.includes("User denied")) {
                    alert("You rejected the transaction on Metamask!")
                } else {
                    alert(error)
                }
            }

        })
    })
```

This doesn't work as intended. How should this be done? The error printed if the user rejects the transaction is:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied
>   transaction signature.

So presumably this should be simple by checking if that's the error message.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find an answer for this using Ethers.js, so here is what I did in case others need it.  It also includes actions while waiting for the block to be mined and after:

```
const functionName = async(...parameters)=>{
   let signedContract = new Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, signer);
   signedContract.method(...parameters)
   .then((tx)=>{
      //action prior to transaction being mined
      provider.waitForTransaction(tx.hash)
      .then(()=>{
         //action after transaction is mined
      })
   })
   .catch(()=>{
   //action to perform when user clicks "reject"
   })
}
```

I think this might be easier to do with Ethers than Web3.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution for this too. I am using truffle and looked up their documentation. 
http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts

```
Contract.deployed().then(function(contractInstance){ 
  contractInstance.function({from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function(result){             
      alert('transaction success')}).catch(function(e){ 
      console.log('error')                                          
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle Confirm/Cancel response of user on your contract functions, you can use the **transactionHash** event & **error** event from send function.

> "transactionHash" returns transactionHash: String: Fired when the transaction hash is available.

> "error" returns error: Error: Fired if an error occurs during sending. If the transaction was rejected by the network with a receipt, the receipt will be available as a property on the error object.[image]

[You can see detail here.](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id36)

When you click on **Confirm** button then you can handle this case in the **transactionHash** event.

When you click on **Cancel** button then you can handle this case in the **error** event.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Following is my code to connect and sign a transaction using Metamask API:

```
async function connectMetamask(){
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined'
      || (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined')) {
      const provider = window['ethereum'] || window.web3.currentProvider
  }
  console.log(ethereum.isMetaMask);

  try {
    const accounts = await ethereum.enable();
    console.log("account: " +  accounts[0]);

    ethereum.send({
      method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
      params: [{"from": accounts[0],
      "to": smartContractaddress,
      "gas": "0x2DC6C0", // 30400
      "gasPrice": "0x2540BE400", 
      "value": weitohex, // 2441406250
      "data": inputhex}],
      from: accounts[0],
    },function(err, transactionHash) {
      if (!err){
        console.log(transactionHash); 
        if(transactionHash.result !== undefined){
          document.getElementById('span_metalink').innerText="https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/"+transactionHash.result;
          document.getElementById('span_metalink').href="https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/"+transactionHash.result;
          document.getElementById('span_success').innerText = "Transaction Successfully Done!!!";
        }
        else{
          document.getElementById('span_success').innerText = "User denied transaction signature.";
        }
      }
    })

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error === "User rejected provider access")
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This migbt be the solution you looked for(Tested with Metamask and Ether.js):

....

```
  }else if(err.code.toString()==='ACTION_REJECTED'){
      //Ignore User rejected
}
```

....

I Know alittle bit dirty, but works